# Bluetooth server on Android Nougat

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, android-7.0-nougat

I have a problem with the `Bluetooth` server on android `Nougat`.

Bluetooth seems to receive data more slowly (maybe it does not have the highest priority?) and then the plot of my charts happens slowly and I lose more data.

There is a big difference between an Nvidia Shield 6.0 and another with `Nougat`.

I had already found a problem on `Nougat` about "sniffing" because if the `Bluetooth` server that I create remains only in reception then after a few seconds stops receiving, I solved sending a useless data once a second and this keeps it awake.

On my **samsung galaxy s7** edge with `Nougat the problem is even bigger because the graph is clearly delayed and when I turn off the communication the graph keeps scrolling as if the data were in the buffer. The delay is many seconds.

With less powerful smartphones but with `Android 6.0` I have no problem.

Does anyone have the same problem and managed to solve it in some way?